# python pandas object type dict error when fetching the value

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, types

I have a data frame df that has >2000 columns with different datatypes. I plan to convert those non-numeric categorical variables into numerical ones. So, I need to get those column names first.

```
col_dataType = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
```

col_dataType is a dictionary with these 3 values

```
col_dataType.keys()
Out: [dtype('O'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64')]
```

Now when I try to fetch the columns with object datatype, i.e, list corresponding to dtype('O')

```
col_dataType["dtype('O')"]
```

it keeps giving me key value error, it does not work either even without double quote. How do I get the column names?

I took unutbu's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`df.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], 'bar':['a','b','c'], 'baz':[1.2,3.4,5.6]})

In [59]: df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])
Out[59]: 
  bar
0   a
1   b
2   c
```

---

The keys in `col_dataType` are of type `numpy.dtype`, not strings:

```
In [67]: [type(item) for item in col_dataType.keys()]
Out[67]: [numpy.dtype, numpy.dtype, numpy.dtype]
```

So

```
In [68]: col_dataType[np.dtype('O')]
Out[68]: ['bar']
```

works, but I think `df.select_dtypes` should be preferred since it uses the
Pandas API method built for this purpose.

Comment: this is a great solution, thanks. But for those without knowing this particular function like me, what is the error with my way, is it a Pandas bug?

Comment: @Jin It is not a Pandas bug. The problem with your way is that `col_dataType` doesn't have a string `"dtype('O')"` as a key.